# is it possible to deploy a mixing of Laravel and Nodejs and angularjs app to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, laravel-4

I was wondering if it is possible to deploy an app (but one that has Laravel 4 ,nodejs angularjs, socketio ) to heroku.
The problem is that I dont really get it,because for nodejs it is necesary to open a terminal and write "node server" to make it run.
But Laravel as the other backend it has a different configuration.

help please.

Answer (score 2):

Yes is it. You can try it out using the larasocial template.

Larasocial is a simple but rich web application build on top of the Laravel framework. Inside you will find features such as friend requesting, chat between users, private messaging and more. To view the app online go to http://larasocial.info

#### Download instructions:

1. git clone https://github.com/msalom28/Larasocial.git projectname
2. composer install (You might get an error with the elephant.io package, The package folder might appear empty after download, just close your text editor and open the project again, and the files will be there. I really don't know why that is happening.)
3. npm install
4. php artisan migrate --seed
5. type "node server.js" in your terminal (leave terminal open with the command running)
6. php artisan serve

Comment: One question, I have the "inverse" situation. I have a laravel project with a few npm packages and compiling assets as scss which are not the core of the app. Then, can I deploy the app in a regular php server or I need to use some cloud computing app like heroku which allows me to deploy it there? Thank you!

Comment: You will need a cloud server like you mentioned (Heroku).
You need to create 2 workers, one for your php app and the other for your compiling assets.